# The subjunctive mood in indirect speech

Tags: subjunctives

> "...There was no point in worrying Mrs Dursley, she always got so
> upset at any mention of her sister. He didn't blame her - **if he'd
> had** a sister like that... but all the same, those people in cloaks..."

I can't understand why the structure "if he'd had" is used instead of "if he had" here. To my understanding, this sentence is describing Mr. Dursley's thought in an indirect form rather than the author's comment.

Comment: This quote should be double-checked. I think the original had mistakes and the edit might have added more mistakes.

Comment: @cruthers, the quote has been checked.

Comment: I think this is just past tense of conditional/subjunctive (sorry, don't know the exact grammatical terms), which would be appropriate for books written in the past tense. In a present tense conversation, I might say to a friend of mine: "If I had a sister like yours, I'd go crazy." Later in our lives, looking back, I might put it all in the past tense say: "If I'd had a sister like yours, I'd have gone crazy."

Comment: Also, I think there should probably be a semicolon, not a comma, in the quote. I'm giving Rowling some credit here.

Comment: @cruthers, thank you for your comments.  To my understanding, this is Mr Dursley's thought here. I think the first "had" describes unreality and the  perfect form of the second "had" describes the continuity of the state.

Comment: I think I agree, though I'm not sure I exactly know what continuity of the state is. In any case, I'm not sure I understand the distinction between indirect speech and the author's comment. I do think that this is Mr. Dursley's thought. Note that there is a missing but implicit "he'd have gone crazy" or the like represented by the "...".

Answer (score 1):

This Quora explains what you are asking quite well:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-have-had-has-had-and-had-had?share=1

> HAD:
>
> possessed/experienced at **a single point** or span of time **in the past**: I
> had a dog. I had a cold. He had a girlfriend.

> HAD HAD
>
> possessed/experienced something starting at some time in the past and
> ending before another time in the past. It contains **a span of time not
> just a single point in time**: I had had a dog for years before getting
> cats. I had had a cold all winter but was fine by spring. He had had a
> girlfriend in school but none since graduating.

Comment: Pretty sure this is wrong, because it ignores the conditional/subjunctive aspect of the quote in the question. The "had" in "If I had a sister like yours" is not the normal past tense "had."